# Unclear choice of polynomial in Gaussian Quadrature method?

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, quadrature

Recently, I have been reading a paper regarding the evaluation of an integral using the Gaussian quadrature method but I cannot understand the rationality behind the weight and orthogonal polynomials the author has chosen.

$\begin{gathered}
  \int\limits_{{s_1}}^{{s_2}} {f\left( x \right)dx}  \approx \frac{{\left( {{s_2} - {s_1}} \right)}}{2}\sum\limits_{s = 1}^{\operatorname{Max} \,\,sample} {\frac{{\pi \sqrt {1 - {v^2}} }}{{\operatorname{Max} \,\,sample}}f\left( u \right)}  \hfill \\
  v = \cos \left( {\frac{{\left( {2s - 1} \right)\pi }}{{2 \times \operatorname{Max} \,\,sample}}} \right) \hfill \\
  u = \frac{{\left( {{s_2} - {s_1}} \right)}}{2}v + \frac{{\left( {{s_2} + {s_1}} \right)}}{2} \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} $

I understand that $u = \frac{{\left( {{s_2} - {s_1}} \right)}}{2}v + \frac{{\left( {{s_2} + {s_1}} \right)}}{2}$ is some smart change of variable to move the integration region to $\left[ { - 1,1} \right]$ but I do not know why a trigonometric function such as cos is chosen ?

From my domain knowledge, in this application the function $f\left( x \right)$ is something that look like a Gaussian bell-shaped. Does this knowledge justify the author's choice ?

Please help me understand this !

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's [Gauss-Chebyshev quadrature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%E2%80%93Gauss_quadrature) and will be the most accurate if $f(x)$ has branch points like $(x-s_1)^{n-1/2}$ and $(s_2-x)^{m-1/2}$ for nonnegative integers $n$ and $m$ at the endpoints. If  $f(x)$ is regular at one or both endpoints, not as great but still can be pretty accurate. For regular $f(x)$ [Gauss-Legendre quadrature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Legendre_quadrature) would be more accurate although it requires more effort to set up. [Clenshaw-Curtis quadrature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clenshaw%E2%80%93Curtis_quadrature) can be easier to set up than Gauss-Legendre in that it uses the straightforward Gauss-Chebyshev quadrature to expand the function $f(x)$ in Chebyshev polynomials and then uses their known integrals. It would take more information to decide whether the author is using an optimal quadrature strategy or something quick and dirty.

**EDIT:** The issue is that the error in Gaussian quadrature is equal to $$\left(\frac{s_2-s_1}L\right)^{2n+1}C_nf^{(2n)}(\xi)$$ where $n$ is the number of data points, $L$ is the length of the model interval, $2$ for Gauss-Chebyshev quadrature, $s_1<\xi<s_2$, and $C_n$ is a constant depending on the quadrature algorithm and the number of data points. If $f(x)$ looks like $\sqrt{x-s_1}$ or $\sqrt{s_2-x}$ at one of its endpoints then the derivatives of $f(x)$ are unbounded so the error could be anything. Gauss-Chebyshev uses a weight function $w(x)=(1-x^2)^{-1/2}$ so this creates an effective $g(x)=\sqrt{(x-s_1)(s_2-x)}f(x)$ and this is the function whose derivatives should all remain finite at the endpoints if we want to impose a bound on the error of the quadrature as given.

As I mentioned, Gauss-Chebyshev quadrature may even give good results if $g(x)$ has unbounded derivatives but other methods may yield better results with fewer data points.

Comment: I am an electrical engineer and I do not receive training in complex analysis so it is a little bit hard for me to understand the word "regular" or "branch point". What do you mean when you said f(x) is regular ?

Comment: If f(x) is the integrand does that mean that g(x) is the summand ?

Comment: Without calling any functions names, the transformation is $$\begin{align}\int_{s_1}^{s_2}f(x)dx&=\int_{s_1}^{s_2}\frac{\sqrt{(x-s_1)(s_2-x)}f(x)dx}{\sqrt{(x-s_1)(s_2-x)}}\\&=\int_{-1}^1\frac{g\left(\frac{s_2-s_1}2u+\frac{s_2+s_1}2\right)}{\sqrt{\frac{s_2-s_1}2(1+u)\frac{s_2-s_1}2(1-u)}}\frac{s_2-s_1}2du\\&=\int_{-1}^1w(u)g\left(\frac{s_2-s_1}2u+\frac{s_2+s_1}2\right)du\\&\approx\sum_{s=1}^NA_sg\left(\frac{s_2-s_1}2u_s+\frac{s_2+s_1}2\right)\end{align}$$ Where each $A_s=\frac{\pi}{N}$ and $u_s=\cos\left(\frac{(2s-1)\pi}{2N}\right)$. Then my $g(\dots)=\frac{s_2-s_1}2\sqrt{1-v^2}f(u)$ ifor you.